# CORDOVA | App that change content with different logins

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm developing a generic app where you can login (after registration) and setting the country, logo and contents changes (getting from an AJAX/PHP script).

However every time I reload a page, it download images and send requests again.
How can I store the info about pages only the first time, when I login in the app?

I must to save file as PERSISTANT with file plugin? And what about HTML content in page (must be dynamic)? Where can I store it? LocalStorage?

Comment: show us what have you tried already

Comment: Nothing! I simply get content with $.ajax and print data in the div elements... but when i go in home and enter again in that page, obviously it will re-send the ajax request for get the content...

There's a away to save all in local for avoid more request if the file is in local?